# Laravel 5.1 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::cookie()

Tags: cookies, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to load the value of a cookie in a controller in Laravel 5.1, but I'm getting this error:

```
FatalErrorException in SurveyController.php line 21: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::cookie()
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Response;
use Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Cookie;
use Log;

class SurveyController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Index method. Decide to resume a survey or start a new one.
     */
    public function index(Request $request) {

        dd($request->cookie('survey_id'));
    }
}
```

From what I can tell from [the documents](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#cookies), this appears to be the correct way to load a cookie value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so instead of

```
use Request;
```

try

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
use Request;
```

which uses Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request

Use

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```